# How can I set the `APS Environment` value in .entitlements to `development` when archiving for testers?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, entitlements

In apps with Push Notification capability turned on, Xcode automatically generates an `<ProjectName>.entitlements` file.

Look like this: 
[image]

Here is the question. Sometimes we may want to use `development` mode in testing archives to avoid mistakenly pushing notifications to normal users. But Xcode automatically use `production` mode when archive, even though you manually set it to `development`.  Is it possible to archive in `development` mode? And if so, how to?

Comment: Yes it it possible. What happens when you manually set it to `development`? I did not clearly understand what the problem is.

Comment: My bad. I didn't make it clear.     When archiving, the actual value used is `production`.

Comment: btw, the aps-environment setting is located in the provisioning profile file (usually in the projects directory). Here is the documentation for setting it's value, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/aps-environment

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/aps-environment):

> Xcode sets the value of the entitlement based on your app's current
>   provisioning profile. For example, if you're using a development
>   provisioning profile, Xcode sets the value to development.

So I guess your problem is that you are using a production provisioning profile and that's why Xcode is automatically  using `production` mode.

You need to generate new **development** provisioning profiles from apple's developer site and use them for your archiving to use `development` APS environment in your archive.

Comment: After I archive and export with the `Development` method of distribution, Xcode uses the `development` mode for apns.